# How to replace GCMBaseIntentService with an equivalent GoogleCloudMessaging methods

Tags: android, android-intent, android-studio, google-cloud-messaging

I'm working to update an android app from 2013, to the new API level 23. It seems much has changed since that time and now.

I have a GCMIntentService class which extends GCMBaseIntentService and it overrides it's concrete methods:

- onError()
- onMessage()
- onRegister()
- onUnregister()

I know it's been replaced by GoogleCloudMessaging class but I don't see any equivalent methods in it's docs. Also here a bunch of methods have been deprecated. I am unsure as how to replace these overriding methods, any help would be much appreciated.

Reference:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging#register(java.lang.String...)

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the [Set up a GCM Client App](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client) on how to set up an IntentService in GCM.

Since its a bit different, you may have to change the way you handled the implementation before. You're basically asked to create an IntentService and get the registration token inside `onHandleIntent` by getting the InstanceId.